# Foreign key location

Tags: foreign-key, erd

This is a question from a Master's degree.

What is the correct response to the question depicted in the image, and why?

Or do you believe there could be multiple correct answers?

[image: Question]

Answer (score 3):

In the relational data model it is a good idea to avoid as much as possible nullable foreign keys.

Assuming that each license has a holder, while a person can have a license or not, this means that the foreign key should go into the table representing licenses, so that it is a not null attribute.

Comment: Is not any option a valid answer? (Given the question)

Comment: Any is not a *completely* wrong answer. It is simply worse than the License answer.

Answer (score 2):

**License** is in a *total participation* relationship with **Person** -- though it is not a weak entity (it has its own primary key, **LicenseNumber**), it cannot exist without a corresponding, single **Person**. To enforce this constraint you must declare a foreign key in **License** to reference that **Person**.

Comment: Ok, but the question is just asking where to put an FK. Both options are valid according to the question. (one better, the other worse, but both are valid) It's not a dogma.

Comment: And the answer is quite clear, it seems to me: "you must declare a foreign key in License". There's no dogma involved, just logical reasoning. You're welcome to provide different reasoning, of course, or ignore the argument altogether.

Comment: Therefore, you say that using an FK in Person would not work? If the question is instead "Provide the best option: given the below Entity Relationship, where do we put the FK?" I would agree with you. (Also logical reasoning)

Comment: A foreign key on **Person** cannot prevent creation of a **License** that references no valid **Person**. Obviously.

Comment: Then do we agree on that your option is the best, but given the question any answer can be valid? (imagine that the business owner says: I want it in a way that I by only querying **Person** table I can know how many people does not have license. Then, wouldn't be the best option **Person**?

Answer (score 1):

According to the diagram:

1. The Person *may* have "zero or one" License
2. The License **must** have "one and only one" Person

Therefore *ideally* the foreign key should only be entered on the License because in an ideal scenario we want all foreign keys to be filled with valid primary key values at all times.

Here's why:

1. This allows us to (if appropriate) enforce foreign key constraints which would be physically implemented with a very efficient primary key lookup
2. It allows for the best query compute and I/O efficiency in real world
   relational database management system implementations

*However...*

If you're dealing with a real world situation where someone has created a nullable foreign key... don't fret unless it has lead to a real world problem. Nullable foreign keys are more common than you might think:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/1723839/19051559

Answer (score -3):

Since the question is not specifying if the FK should be put in a table to avoid nulls as much as possible, any answer can be valid.

Person, License or "any" are valid.

Comment: No, this is wrong. The image clearly indicates where the FK should be.

Comment: I understand the point of all of you. But I am asking for "valid answer", given the question. Both cases can be implemented in a database. (theory says "best option" is to put "FK" in optional modality, but this question is not asking for the "best option")

Comment: I suppose this comment is going to be removed... But I just wanted to say that this is amazing, how all of you answered and have given your expert opinion. It's the first time I use this kind of forums, and I believe I will come more often and contribute. This site, and all the contributors, you are awesome. Thanks ypercube, and rest of users who answered. Also thanks Paul White to update/moderate the comments and the question.